# How to convert a String to actual file that was generated from FileReader.readAsDataURL()

Tags: javascript, web, filereader

I have generated a string of a file using this:

```
const reader = new window.FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onloadend = () => {
  var x = reader.result.toString();
  console.log("File String :: ", x);
};
```

How to convert this string to actual file like if the previous file was a PDF then this string will converted to a pdf file 
`reader.result.toString()`  gives me a string like this `"data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJSDi48/..........."`
I want to convert it back to pdf
[FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

Comment: What do you mean by "the actual file"?  Or more importantly, what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I Want to convert this string to the main file format. Like if the file was in pdf then converting it back to a pdf file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript/247261#247261  The api for `readAsDataURL` references that the result of the method will be the contents of the file in base64.  So it appears what you are asking is how to convert back from base64.

Comment: Like after converting it to string it gives me a string like this : ```data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJSDi48/...........``` I want to convert it back to pdf

Comment: This is not a duplicate, while the [marked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801) deals with encoding/decoding base64 strings it does not answer op's question of how to get a file object from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a base64 string use [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) to decode it and then use the [`Blob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) constructor to get a Blob object (super constructor to File)

```
//strip off the data uri prefix
let encodedString = dataUrlString.replace('data:application/pdf;base64,','')
let data = atob(encodedString);
let blob = new Blob([data],{'type':'optional mime type here'});

//if you need a literal File object
let file = new File(blob,"filename.pdf",{type:"optional mime type"});
```